# Is it possible to obtain the date/time of streamed tweets using Twitter's API V2 in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

**I don't know if it's possible, but is there a way to get the date/time of each tweet that comes through Twitter's Filtered Stream?**

I'm using sample code provided in Twitter's API V2 documentation for "filtered stream" tweets as a base. I have edited it so that I can search for a key word, and I am able to just get the text of the tweets, but I also want to get the date/time of the tweets. I can't seem to be able to do it.

**My goal is to be able to count the number of tweets created every 15min that contains my word/s of interest, but I can't do this without having the time the tweets were created.**

Here is my code so far:

````
import requests
import os
import json
import config
import preprocessor as p
from csv import writer


# To set your enviornment variables in your terminal run the following line:
# export 'BEARER_TOKEN'='<your_bearer_token>'
bearer_token = config.BEARER_TOKEN


def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2FilteredStreamPython"
    return r


def get_rules():
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules", auth=bearer_oauth
    )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.text, response.created_at)
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))
    return response.json()


def delete_all_rules(rules):
    if rules is None or "data" not in rules:
        return None

    ids = list(map(lambda rule: rule["id"], rules["data"]))
    payload = {"delete": {"ids": ids}}
    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
        auth=bearer_oauth,
        json=payload
    )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot delete rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))


def set_rules(delete):
    # You can adjust the rules if needed
    sample_rules = [
        {"value": "(AVAX OR #AVAX OR AVAX/USDT OR AVAXUSDT OR AVAXUSD OR AVALANCHEAVAX OR #AVALANCHEAVAX) lang:en -giveaway -jackpot -jackpots -collectable -collectible -collection"},#-passive -prize -prizes -giveaways -tag -YouTube -dickhead -rank -ranked -rewards -link -visit -game -promotion -promote -vote -colony -retweet -Regards -discord -jizz -tits -join -airdrop -earn -retweets -contest -shib -shiba -is:retweet -is:reply -has:links"},
     #   {"value": "cat has:images -grumpy", "tag": "cat pictures"},
    ]
    payload = {"add": sample_rules}
    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
        auth=bearer_oauth,
        json=payload,
    )
    if response.status_code != 201:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot add rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))


def get_stream(set):
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream", auth=bearer_oauth, stream=True,
    )
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get stream (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
           # print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            tweet = json_response['data']['text']
            tweet = p.clean(tweet)
            print(tweet)
            tweetList = [tweet]
            
            with open('avaxdata.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
                csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
                csv_writer.writerow(tweetList)

def main():
    rules = get_rules()
    delete = delete_all_rules(rules)
    set = set_rules(delete)
    get_stream(set)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big shout out to **Alan Lee** for steering me in the right direction.
I included the link he provided under the **get_stream** function:

```
def get_stream(set):
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=created_at,text", auth=bearer_oauth, stream=True,
    )
```

Notice I also added the '**text**' parameter to the end because I wanted both the time the tweet was created, and what the actual tweet said.

The full **get_stream** function which allows me to get the date and text, and have it cleaned, and stored into a csv in two separate columns (text, date) is as below:

**NOTE:** Make sure to install *'tweet-preprocessor'* and **NOT** *'preprocessor'*... they are different, and the latter one won't work with this code.

```
import preprocessor as p
from csv import writer

def get_stream(set):
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=created_at,text", auth=bearer_oauth, stream=True,
    )
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get stream (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
            tweet_text = json_response['data']['text']
            tweet_created_at = json_response['data']['created_at']
            tweet_text = p.clean(tweet_text)
            
            print(tweet_text)
            print(tweet_created_at)
            
            tweetList = [(tweet_text),(tweet_created_at)]
            
            with open('avaxdata.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
                csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
                csv_writer.writerow(tweetList)
```

I hope someone out there finds this useful! Took me a lot longer than it should have just to get this working haha!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add on additional `field` parameters to the endpoint. To get the created at times for Tweets, try `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=created_at`.
For full list of optional params check out the API reference [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-search-stream)